# Cannot Correctly Scan File for LinkedList

Tags: c

I need help figuring out how to properly scan a file of text to put information into a linked list. The file is:

```
12   JackSprat   2     1    65000

13   HumptyDumpty  5   3    30000

17   BoPeep  2       3      30000

20   BoyBlue    3    2      58000

0
```

0 Is the indicator as to when the file has ended. Whenever I run my code, it loops 5 times, but only saves the first line. When I print the information of the linked list it just prints the first line 5 times. I need to read the whole file and then stop at 0 but I'm pretty stumped. Here is my code.

```
struct employeeData* initializeList(struct employeeData *head, FILE *ifp ){
struct employeeData *temptr;
struct employeeData *newnode;

printf("testin\n");

    while(!feof(ifp))
    {
        newnode = (struct employeeData*)malloc(sizeof(struct employeeData));

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = newnode;
            head->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            temptr = head;
            while(temptr->next != NULL)
            {
                temptr = temptr->next;
            }
            temptr->next = newnode;

        }
        fscanf(ifp, "%d%s%d%d%lf", &newnode->EMP_ID, &newnode->name, &newnode->dept, &newnode->rank, &newnode->salary);
    }

return head;}
```

What is really weird is if I delete printf("testin\n"); the code then crashes at the cmd prompt.

Comment: Curious: What or who suggested using `while(!feof(ifp))` to detect when to stop reading?

Comment: First of all, don't to `while (!feof(...))`, it will not work as you expect it to. The reason us that the eof flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of the file. That means your loop will iterate once to many, and you will have two nodes at the end with the same data.

Comment: Suggest `newnode->name` in `fscanf()` rather than `&newnode->name`.

Comment: No one, I'm temporarily using it to actually scan the file. If I do something like while(fscanf(ifp, "%d", &newnode->EMP_ID)!=0) it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks a bit as if there was an error when scanning your format and that you scan the same line over and over. Use `fscanf`s return value to check for success.

Comment: You want something like `while(fscanf(ifp, "%d", &newnode->EMP_ID)==1)`

Comment: As for using `while (fscanf(...) != 0)`, remember that on error or end of file `fscanf` will return `EOF` which is not equal to zero. I recommend e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: Hmm so I tested to see if my fscan was scanning properly, and I'm actually scanning through the whole file correctly. Now I just need to know how to stop at 0. I tried while(fscanf(ifp, "%d", &newnode->EMP_ID)==1) and it doesn't seem to be correct for me. Debugger says it expected statement before ')' token - NVM but it still crashes on startup.

Comment: Recommend scanning in the entire line via `fgets()`.  Then start parsing it looking for a line that begins with `0` to stop gracefully, or successfully scans all 5 fields, or failing those 2, errors out.

Comment: Post the definition of `struct employeeData`.

Comment: `newnode = (struct employeeData*)malloc(sizeof(struct employeeData));` and need `newnode->next = NULL;`

Comment: why you traverse the list all the time to find the tail, you can just remember the tail.

Comment: Akin to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024824/issue-adding-and-deleting-nodes-from-a-linked-list

Comment: Yes Chux, same assignment I guess but I'm not using her method at all and I don't plan on sharing code with people. That's why I only posted a snippet of mine for help with that part. But as for what he's asking about deletion, when I delete the head of my linked list, and print the new list, there are still some junk values left behind. When I delete any other node it deletes everything. Any clue as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newnode = (struct employeeData*)malloc(sizeof(struct employeeData));
add string: newnode->next = NULL;

or use calloc

if head != NULL then return unchanged head, this is exactly what you wanted?

Comment: Yes thank you that solved my program crashing if I deleted the printf statement. But the question still remains of how to break out of the while loop once it reads that 0. For now I can use a for loop because I know how many lines to read but thing is the amount of lines read can be changed. So somehow the while loop needs to know when it reads in that 0 at the end.

Comment: you can not use the feof() function, but you have to do like this:

fscanf("%d", &tmp); if (!tmp) { //loop should be terminated } else { //store the tmp value into corresponding structure field }
Then continue to read the file but without first value of the string