# Issue adding and deleting nodes from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I have a program that has to take in input from a text file, create a linked list with this input, then be able to add, delete, modify, and query the linked list.

My query and modify functions work fine. My delete function fails under a particular case, and I'm struggling with the add function. No errors from the compiler to help out. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could point me in the right direction.

The add function is giving me the biggest problems. After a couple hours of debugging and help from a coworker, the closest I've gotten to adding anything is changing

UPDATED: Thanks everyone for the feedback! I ended up discovering the major issue I was having with the help of a co-worker. Apparently I was passing around a value instead of a reference. ** did the trick for both add and delete functions.

```
void add(employee **head, int addEMP_ID, char* addName, int addDept, int addRank, double addSalary) {
}

void delete(employee **head, int option) {
}
```

Comment: Same assignment as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023705/cannot-correctly-scan-file-for-linkedlist ?

Comment: yep looks like the same assignment. I've seen a lot of them on here, all with slightly different ways of doing things, and slightly different issues.

Comment: Start a pseudo OOP there. Make a `struct List{}` and pass the pointer to it around instead of `head`

Comment: Are you deleting one node per time?

Comment: yep, only one node will be deleted at a time

Answer (score 0):

If the head node is the one you want to delete, it will be freed after the function delete is called. However, the head pointer is still pointing to the head node which is already freed. This is the reason that cause the seg fault.

One way to change is :

```
void delete(employee **head, int option) {

employee* current;
employee *del;
current = *head;

if (current != NULL) {
    if (current->EMP_ID == option) {
        del = *head;
        *head = *head->next;
        free(del);
        return;
    }
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        if (current ->next->EMP_ID == option) {
            del = current -> next;
            current->next = current ->next->next;
            free(del);
            return;
        }
    current = current -> next;
    }
}
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider.

Start a pseudo-OOP going, pass around a pointer to `struct List` rather than `struct Node`.

```
typedef struct structList {
    employeeData *head; 
}  EmployeeList;
```

Use the [double-pointer iterator](http://www.mvps.org/user32/linkedlist.html) to insert and delete.

Comment: How does adding a wrapper around the head node help?  Any node can be a head of its own list... it's a linked list.

Comment: @EdS.: Actually, a linked list only has one head - the pointer to the first node in the list. That's the pointer used to represent the entire list. Any other pointer to a node is not a head, just a regular pointer. That's what `EmployeeList` is supposed to emphasize.